# how to populate /sys in a initramfs?

Tags: linux, initramfs

I'm trying to boot an OS (linux kernel) using the debian kernel so i needed to use an initramfs (as everything is builded as modules). But after booting into the initramfs, it doesn't seems to populate /sys/blocks as:

```bsh
# mdev -s
```

"failed" to populate dev with devices (/dev/sd[a-z][0-9]).

Then how should i populate "/sys" correctly? i'm booting the system with qemu and using an raw image as "hd".

Notes:
 * this isn't debian (or any other distro for that matter), and my initramfs is created from scratch
 * i'm using mdev
 * the /init script looks like this:

```bsh
mount -n -t proc none /proc
mount -n -t sysfs none /sys
mkdir /.root
mdev -s
mount -n -t $rootfstype $device /.root
umount /proc
umount /sys
exec switch_root /.root $init $@
```

EDIT: My problem **is not** populating dev, that could be done by hand if necessary, just looking at "/sys" and using "mknod". The problem is "/sys" lacking devices "/sys/block/sd[a-z][0-9]".

dmesg: https://bin.privacytools.io/?d50e11eea81d8158#1ga51UE+NI6nX49SbkdjGitXOyZpalWUu2I3BuEMx+o=
(As i copied it from the qemu curses, i may have missed something)

Comment: By mounting sysfs?

Comment: isn't ```mount -n -t sysfs none /sys``` exactly for that?

Comment: Most of your question seems to be about /sys, but you say ""failed" to populate dev with devices". Which do you really care about, /sys or /dev?

Comment: in order to populate "/dev" with devices "/sys" must have them first, so i care about the devices appearing inside "/sys/block" (which is empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `mdev`, you'll need to have `CONFIG_UEVENT_HELPER=y` in your kernel configuration, and one command before your `mdev -s`:

```
echo /sbin/mdev > /proc/sys/kernel/hotplug
mdev -s
```

Source: [Gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#Dynamic_devices)

The default Debian 10 kernel does not have `CONFIG_UEVENT_HELPER` set, so `mdev` is not going to be usable with it. Instead, it has `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y` so you could do this instead:

```
mount -n -t proc none /proc
mount -n -t sysfs none /sys
mount -n -t devtmpfs none /dev
mkdir /.root
# this would be a great place to run "fsck -C0 $device" if required by $rootfstype
mount -n -t $rootfstype $device /.root
umount /proc
umount /sys
umount /dev
exec switch_root /.root $init $@
```

... and after the switch to the real root filesystem is complete, you can again mount the `devtmpfs` filesystem:

```
mount -n -t devtmpfs none /dev
```

Comment: ```mdev -s``` would work even without this flag to the kernel, it just shouldn't work as a hotplug. anyway this will not solve the problem, the devices will not appear inside "/dev" as they doesn't exist at "/sys" (devtmpfs as the first thing that i were using before trying mdev (as i had the intention of using it as hotplug))

Comment: It might be that your initramfs script runs `mdev -s` when the kernel is still busy probing hardware, and has not detected the disks yet. Probing the PCI(e) bus, loading the storage controller driver, activating the controller and probing for disks can take several hundreds of milliseconds (that's ages in computer timescales), and once you're past `mdev -s` in your script, you won't get any further devices unless you have hotplug enabled. In modern multi-core computers, several things tend to happen in parallel. When writing startup scripts, you must deal with it.

Comment: I have added a call to a shell inside /init, if that were the case shouldn't i see them appearing there at some moment?

Comment: Have all the modules required to support your root disk been loaded? If not, something required by the module autoloading mechanism might be missing. The output of the `dmesg` command might provide more clues.

Comment: no module loaded automatically, but doing it manually didn't made appear the devices. (I loaded: scsi_mod, ata_generic, ata_piix)

Comment: Then you're missing one module: `sd_mod`. And it's the one that provides overall support for disk-like storage devices.

Comment: Perfect, worked now. Those modules aren't loaded automatically by the kernel, so i suppose that "udev" is who does that usually, correct? Anyway thank your for your help